# The correct stress in "transferring"

Tags: word-stress

Where do I need to put the stress in the word "transferring"? Should it be "tRANsferring" or "transFERring"?

CONFUSION:
Many dictionaries say that the noun is "tRANsfer" while the verb is "transFER". Since in the -ing form "transferring" the last letter is doubled ("rr") in all dictionaries, the stress in the verb then must be as "transFERring". However, the GoogleTranslate reads it as "tRANsferring".

As for what part of speech I mean by "transferring" here, I think it is not important as the stress usually stays on the same syllable of "-ing" forms regardless of their function in the sentence.

Comment: There are plenty of words in English – and _transferring_ may well be one of them – where the location of the stress depends on your location, region, and accent, as well as the context (such as whether the word is being used as a noun or verb). Words like _envelope_ and _produce_ are certainly on that list.

Answer (score 1):

You will hear it both ways.

For what it is worth, in southern British English it is indeed usually TRANSfer and transFERring. My hunch is that that is the most common way of doing it worldwide, and nobody would criticise you for saying it that way.

Answer (score 1):

As an American, I normally hear/say TRANSfer (noun) and either TRANSfer or transFER (verb). I only ever say transFERring.